# Is there a way to check NOEXEC state?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I've been searching for a while and can't find anything to start with. If this is a duplicate I'm deeply sorry but maybe my keywords while googling weren't the best.

I have a bunch of scripts that start with a IF and if that IF is True then the NOEXEC flag is set to ON

Something like this

```
if TRUE
BEGIN
    SET NOEXEC ON;  
END
```

the thing is when I execute any script after NOEXEC has been set to ON it wont run. I've already tested and if I do SET NOEXEC OFF the rest of the scripts run without a problem.

```
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script)
```

do I have anyway to check the state of NOEXEC or should I just append it to the start of all of my scripts?

Thanks everybody

Edit: Example of scripts to better explain the problem

1º Script

```
select * from List
print'Done printing'
```

2º Script

```
SET NOEXEC ON;
select * from List
print'Won't print'
```

3º Script

```
select * from List
print'Done printing'
```

My expected result would be having two 'Done printing' messages on my FileInfoMessage but unless I execute a SET NOEXEC OFF I only get the print from the first message

Comment: `when I execute any script after NOEXEC has been set to ON it wont run` - that is kind of a point with noexec. If you don't want this behaviour, why are you using it in the first place?

Comment: Where's the script, how do you run it, what is the behaviour you expected and what is the *actual* behaviour? There's no `ConnectionContext` in ADO.NET which suggests you are using SQLCLR. Why?

Comment: Ok I expresed myself poorly! I'll edit the question

Comment: And yes, `when I execute any script after NOEXEC has been set to ON it wont run` [that's what it's for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-noexec-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Don't use it if you don't want it. I'd have to ask though, *why* do you use it at all?

Comment: Edited with further explanation.
I'm using SMO since the scripts I have to handle have a lot of GO statements

Comment: @AimForNuts that doesn't explain why you use `NOEXEC` or why you want to change its value. `NOEXEC ON` means someone or something wants to *validate* the script, not run it. Running a script that wasn't meant to run is a really bad idea

Comment: a) Use separate connections for each script. b) Turn noexec off in the end of each script where you turn it on.

Comment: In your example, whoever wrote the 2nd script wanted to validate the syntax, *not* read an entire table

Comment: The scripts are used for data update on the database. If the database has a version higher than the version of the script it shouldn't run the script. Therefore the developer that writed the script used NOEXEC.
I want to change NOEXEC value because I'm running a bunch of scripts and if one sets NOEXEC to ON it shouldn't be set to the other scripts

Comment: @GSerg guess that's the way to go.
New connections. 
About the noexec off I'm not the one writing the scripts but the develop team will be advised ofc

Thanks you

Comment: The problem with `noexec` is that when it's on, if you issue an sql command that supposedly fetches its current status, it would not execute because noexec is on. So while there is a way to [query the current `SET` flags](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1415/determining-set-options-for-a-current-session-in-sql-server/), there isn't one for noexec.

Comment: Can you please post that not as a comment so I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set noexec on` stops executing the SQL commands until a `set noexec off` is encountered.

It there was a command that fetches the current state of noexec, it would not execute either because `noexec` would be on. If it did execute at all, that would mean noexec is off.

Arguably, the design team could come up with a yet another "special" command that bypasses the `noexec on` state and executes anyway (like `set noexec off` does), giving you the current state of `noexec`. As far as I know, such command does not exist, so while there is a way to [query the current `SET` flags](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1415/determining-set-options-for-a-current-session-in-sql-server/), there isn't one for noexec.

You can:

- Use a new connection object for each script
- Turn `noexec off` in the end of each script where you turn it on
- Execute a dummy `select 1`. If you get `1` back, noexec is off.

Answer (score 2):

Bizarrely, you need to use a contradiction to find out.

When NOEXEC is on, the argument of an IF statement isn't executed, instead it always evaluates to TRUE. So "IF 1=0" is a good enough contradiction to detect this.

```sql
-- Try one or the other of these statements
SET NOEXEC ON;
-- SET NOEXEC OFF;

IF 1=0
BEGIN
    SET NOEXEC OFF
    PRINT 'noexec was on'
    SET NOEXEC ON
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'noexec was off'
END
```

Note that we have to turn NOEXEC off temporarily so we can PRINT the "noexec was on" message.